# What does y do in enumerator.new do |y|

Tags: ruby, enumerator

I can't wrap my head around it. I tried to consult [ruby-doc on enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerator.html) but it did not help much.

From ruby-doc:

```
fib = Enumerator.new do |y|
  a = b = 1
  loop do
    y << a
    a, b = b, a + b
  end
end
```

What I don't understand is, why can't I just write `fib = Enumerator.new`, but I have to write `fib = Enumerator.new do |y|`?

What type of object is `y`? What is `y` doing when `fib.next` is executed or when `fib.take(5)` is executed?

Answer (score 1):

The form you are using accepts a block as an argument in which the value `y` can be anything you want it to be.

When `fib.next` is called, the value `y` is "yielded" to the caller. As you can see in your example, the block calls loop and calculates a value each iteration. So `y` is an array that accumulates values.

So calling `take(10)` on the fib enumerator "yields" the first ten fibonacci numbers. Calling next would "yield" the eleventh and so on. This enumerator can be seen as "infinite" even though they do not need to be.

Another contrived example:

```
concat = Enumerator.new do |c|
    cat = "concat"
    loop do
        c << cat
        cat += "concat"
    end
end

p concat.take(5)
```

Here, the enumerator yields a string of "concat" over and over. [This](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/10/02/enumerator-rubys-versatile-iterator/) is an older article, but enumerators are enumerable so you can use the methods in this class as well as seen by calling `take`.

Answer (score 0):

> What I don't understand is, why can't I just write fib = Enumerator.new, but I have to write fib = Enumerator.new do |y|?

You've created an enumerator that doesn't evaluate anything until you call either `next` or `take(5)`

`y` is the locally scoped variable that references your enumerator. Essentially, you are yielding the enumerator to the block `do..end` and applying your own logic on the enumerator, so when it is accessed, it evaluates to the value you want.